# Version of hbase and zookeeper

Tags: hadoop, compatibility, hbase

I have currently started using the following configuration of "hbase 90.5" with
"hadoop 20.205". I want to set up the zookeeper too.

Can anybody please tell which version of Zookeeper will go fine with the above version of hbase ?

Thanks

Harry

Answer (score 2):

HBase 0.90.5 uses `ZooKeeper 3.3.2` . Have a look at its `pom.xml` :

```
<zookeeper.version>3.3.2</zookeeper.version>
```